# Is it legal for a lambda to odr-use this or a not captured entity with automatic storage duration in C++20?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#8) of the final draft of C++17 N4659:

> An entity is captured if it is captured explicitly or implicitly. An entity captured by a lambda-expression is odr-used in the scope containing the lambda-expression. If *this is captured by a local lambda expression, its nearest enclosing function shall be a non-static member function. If a lambda-expression or an instantiation of the function call operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses this or a variable with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity shall be captured by the lambda-expression. If a lambda-expression captures an entity and that entity is not defined or captured in the immediately enclosing lambda expression or function, the program is ill-formed.

However, [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#8) of the final draft of C++20 N4861:

> An entity is captured if it is captured explicitly or implicitly. An entity captured by a lambda-expression is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) in the scope containing the lambda-expression. [ Note: As a consequence, if a lambda-expression explicitly captures an entity that is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed ([basic.def.odr]). — end note ]

It removes the description that `this` or such entities should be captured in this case. **Does it mean they don't need to be captured (of course, that's not possible)? Or is it explained elsewhere?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, I find this GitHub repository https://github.com/cplusplus/draft is useful in finding out how things changed between different C++ standards. In particular, I found [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/2013572d281d6405d40713ef7da542b6230b7a5f) using `git blame`, which is the result of [P0588R1: Simplifying implicit lambda capture](https://wg21.link/P0588R1) (to resolve [CWG 1632. Lambda capture in member initializers](http://wg21.link/cwg1632))

It seems that this has been moved to [[basic.def.odr]p9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#9) in N4861:

> A local entity ([basic.pre]) is odr-usable in a declarative region ([basic.scope.declarative]) if:
>
> - (9.1) either the local entity is not *this, or an enclosing class or non-lambda function parameter scope exists and, if the innermost such scope is a function parameter scope, it corresponds to a non-static member function, and
> - (9.2) for each intervening declarative region ([basic.scope.declarative]) between the point at which the entity is introduced and the region (where *this is considered to be introduced within the innermost enclosing class or non-lambda function definition scope), either:
>
>   - (9.2.1) the intervening declarative region is a block scope, or
>   - (9.2.2) the intervening declarative region is the function parameter scope of a **lambda-expression that has a simple-capture naming the entity or has a capture-defaul**t, and the block scope of the lambda-expression is also an intervening declarative region.
>
> If a local entity is odr-used in a declarative region in which it is not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

(emphasis mine)

So for an automatic variable or `this` to be odr-usable, they need to be captured.

Comment: Thanks, I will suggest adding a note.